# Magento 2: Question about set reindex (update on schedule or update on save)

Tags: magento2, cron, index

I have a script that is responsible for automatic updating of states with an external storage (automatically adds products and automatically updates states) every 15 minutes.

How to set index? Please reply me

```
***Should by:***

 - Update on schedule or 
 - Update on save?
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case you I think you should use **Update on Save**

Update on Save is easiest to explain. Whenever an entity is added, changed, or removed via the admin panel or via a REST request, all necessary indexes are updated to accommodate this change. Quite a number of extra SQL queries are executed in the same request that inserts, updates or deletes the entity. The index is not completely rebuild, it is just modified a little. Specific parts of caches are cleared immediately to ensure that the change is visible on the webshop.

a nice explanation is written [here](https://www.bigbridge.nl/blog/essential-magento-2-partial-reindexing/)